# How to execute in PHP exec() without input file?

Tags: php, exec

I want to make a real time Octave compiler in PHP.[image]

**The first problem** is that I haven't found the solution how to execute in PHP that input would be a command, for example, a=5, but not a file like in the code example below:

```
<?php 
// example with file input
exec("url_to_compiler url_to_the_file 2>&1", $output);
?>
```

**The second problem** is that I've spent much time searching in Google and I haven't found how to load only one time exec() function that could accept many inputs as in the picture above.

Can you give me the solutions how to solve these problems? Maybe should I use other PHP funcion for execution?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP - you need to figure out how to pass your inputs to octave directly on the command line or via stdin. Once you've got that figured out, the PHP portion will be trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send commands and retrieve answers from the launched command you have to use [proc_open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) and handle the read / write pipes yourself.
You also could find several libraries helping you achieve this since it might not be a really straightforward code to properly handle all the situations that might arise if you are not familiar with that.